# Passing object through components using service in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, frontend

I have one doubt regarding the components communication using services.

Now I have one parent component, where I am rendering the list array of objects in parent component using NgFor. Whenever I click any particular item, a function gets triggered and specific object is passed in that function.

Then I am using subject and Observables to load that particular data in a child component. Everything looks fine,  but here am trying to access that particular item before the triggering of the function, so in console.log am getting the errors like `Cannot read property 'movie_id' of undefined)`

Comment: How can anyone help if you don't show us your code... Please take a look at this link :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AJT_82 you can use `[mcve]` in a comment, it will get expanded into this: [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

add an *ngIf to child component regarding the particular data.. that way Angular doesn't try to access the 'movie_id' container object before it exists..

for example, if you have `myObj = { ..., movie_id: 'tarzan' }` add a `*ngIf="myObj"`